# Why I get error 409 when execute Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, runtime-error

We have developed several projects in Apps Script and customers we are reporting several cases of "NetworkError: There was an error in the connection Because HTTP 409" and we would like to know if anyone has been able to identify the problem and even better if you have found a solution.

I will appreciate any help.

[image: Image error]

Comment: There is an old issue [Repeat http 409 errors in add-ons](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62013415) that is getting a lot of recent comments about the same problem.

Comment: @Rubén thanks I didn't read that very carefully I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here it's an updated link about the issue you're having [http 409 error](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143438990).

As it says the technical engineers are still investigating the cause of the problem.

Please refer to this Issue instead of the one linked in the comments.